# Image-rendering madness with incorrect colors in Gecko (Firefox) and Trident (IE) vs. Webkit (Chrome and Safari)

Tags: image, firefox, google-chrome, rendering, gecko

I've designed a website so that an image on the left seamlessly blends into the background color on the right without transparency (the color is simply matched on the far right border of the image to the background). The way the image is, it would be exceedingly difficult to make a cutout with transparency so this solution tends to work well (see the example to see why).

The far right of the image is the hex color `#d0d9e0` according to Photoshop CS5, and I've written CSS appropriately

```
body {
    background-color:#d0d9e0;
    background-image:url('image.jpg');
    background-size:auto 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

In Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) the image blends in beautifully with the background and the result is great. In Gecko browsers (Firefox) and Trident browsers (IE) the color is rendered incorrectly either in the image or the background and it just looks amateur.

To illustrate this unique problem you can see the live test example here: http://ezrahub.com/missmaryland/

Try looking in different browsers to discover where my frustration's coming from. Is there any way to fix this besides using image transparency (you can see why it's frustrating here)? I know Gecko vs. Webkit render images differently but I can't think of an excuse for straight-up color inaccuracy. AGHHHHHH

Comment: Another comment: I know the Red vs. Green and Red vs. Blue thing in Chrome vs. Firefox and I'm not sure if this could be related. Example here: http://i.imgur.com/pHszy.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in how different browsers handle color-managed content. The Photoshop ICC profile included in your file is being interpreted differently (or ignored) in different browsers.

My guess is that you're saving your bitmaps using File > Save As, and if you use File > Save for Web and Devices, you'll get the results you expect.

Comment: This works. It's unfortunate that no other browser does this. I went and saved the JPEG using the Save for Web and Devices option, changed the background to `#dbe1e6` (the sRBG version with no color management) and it works. Sigh... one day Mozilla will get up to speed.

Comment: I agree. That said, I used to see issues in Chrome where the profile was applied repeatedly, and colors would become more and more saturated. Good luck with the site.

Comment: Browser inconsistencies are the bane of many a developer/designer. Thank you and thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Actually, Mozilla does color-correction per the color profile on images by default while WebKit does not, last I checked.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky True, I've researched this and it's more complex than I stated. Edited the answer. See http://gearoracle.com/tools/web-browser-color-management-test/ for a test -- both Chrome and Firefox are failing in different ways for me.